# Why are other terms ignored when computing the derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I've came across [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-introduction.html) tutorial site on computing the derivative of a function.

The function is:

$f(x) = x^3$

Then computing the derivative of the function I get this:

$f(x+ \Delta x) = 3x^2 + 3x \Delta x+ \Delta x^2$

Based on the tutorial, the derivative of $x^2$ is $3x^2$.

My question is, why are the other terms ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compute from first principles, you are finding the limit as $\Delta x$ tends to $0$.  The other terms are not ignored, but evaluate to $0$ as they are multiplied by $0$.

Comment: i apologize for my ignorance, but what does it mean when you say, as x tends to 0?

Comment: When you differentiate from first principles, you are finding the gradient.  So essentially, the rise over run.  The rise is $f(x+\Delta x)$ and the run is $\Delta x$.  You want to find the limit as $\Delta x$ tends to $0$ because this finds the gradient at a point.

Comment: thank you very much for your time, things are quite clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is defined as $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$

Hence \begin{align}\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}&\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{x^3+3x^2\Delta x+3x\Delta x^2+\Delta x^3-x^3}{\Delta x} \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}3x^2+3x\Delta x +\Delta x^2\\&=3x^2\end{align}

Remark: The $f(x+\Delta x)$ in the question is actually $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$